# in sudo update (after a node instalation) i get all these .. I really don't understand

Tags: 20.04

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 71076 (apt-get)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (stable/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
```

Comment: Also, you should wait until "`process 71076 (apt-get)`" finishes, or `kill` it, if it's hung up.